# Loading DataFrame from Pandas to SQL for ORACLE Yields and ERROR - ORA-00911: Invalid Character

Tags: python, oracle, pandas

I am attempting to load a dataframe from Pandas to Oracle. I can read_sql just fine, but df.to_sql does not work.

Here is the error:

```
Error on sql SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='table_name_here'; Traceback (most recent call last): File "
<stdin>", line 1, in
  <module>
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1261, in to_sql self, name, con, flavor=flavor, if_exists=if_exists, **kwargs) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 207, in write_frame exists = table_exists(name,
    con, flavor) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 275, in table_exists return len(tquery(query, con)) > 0 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 90, in tquery cur = execute(sql, con, cur=cur) File
    "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 47, in execute cur.execute(sql) cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00911: invalid character
```

I am doing this as for my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import cx_Oracle

engine = create_engine('oracle://name:pass@server.domain.com:port/sid')
cnx = engine.raw_connection()

merged = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('name.csv', sep=',', index_col=False)
merged.to_sql('schema.table_name_here', cnx, if_exists='append')
```

And I have also tried by adding the schema like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import cx_Oracle

engine = create_engine('oracle://name:pass@server.domain.com:port/sid')
cnx = engine.raw_connection()

merged = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('name.csv', sep=',', index_col=False)
merged.to_sql('table_name_here', cnx, schema='name', if_exists='append')
```

Per Joris, I tried:

```
>>> merged.to_sql('name_of_table', engine, schema='XXCOST', if_exists='append')
Error on sql SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND  name='name_of_table';
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1261,  in to_sql
self, name, con, flavor=flavor, if_exists=if_exists, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 207, in  write_frame
exists = table_exists(name, con, flavor)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 275, in table_exists
return len(tquery(query, con)) > 0
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 90, in tquery
cur = execute(sql, con, cur=cur)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 53, in execute
con.rollback()
AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'rollback'
```

Joris determined my Pandas version was out of date at 13.1 and not 15.2. I updated it and have added the new error below.

```
>>> merged.to_sql('name_of_table', ora, schema='schema',     if_exists='append')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 966, in to_sql
dtype=dtype)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 538, in to_sql
chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1504, in to_sql
table.create()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 637, in create
if self.exists():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 625, in exists
return self.pd_sql.has_table(self.name, self.schema)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1514, in has_table
return len(self.execute(query).fetchall()) > 0
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1421, in execute
raise_with_traceback(ex)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1410, in execute
cur.execute(*args)
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM   sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='name_of_table';':     ORA-00911: invalid character
```

Comment: You should  provide the `engine` itself to `to_sql`, and not the raw connection? (a connection is only supported for sqlite, and not for other database flavors) And a second question: what version of pandas do you have?

Comment: Hey there. Thanks for the tip, I'll give it a try. I am using 15.2.

Comment: @joris, I tried your suggestion and added the response I got from to the question above. One more thing; when using read_sql I do present the raw connection as - xx = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.TABLE', cnx) and that works just fine.

Comment: Looking at the error traceback, I don't think you are using pandas 0.15.2. Can you show the output of `pd.__version__`? (maybe it is picking up an older system pandas?)

Comment: @joris, you were right. I was on 13.1 (installed via repo, not pip) So updated it. I have added the new and updated error above.

Comment: @joris, I have a feeling it's the semi colon at WHERE type='table' AND name='name_of_table';':... But I am unsure.

Comment: What is `ora`? A connection or an engine? The error you see seems to mean that pandas thinks you are writing to an sqlite database (that query is to determine if a table exists, but is specific for sqlite, and therefore you get an error with oracle)

Comment: @joris, sorry, ora is the renamed connection (was originally cnx). Yeah, I was curious about why I was getting sqlite errors. The weird part is that I can use that connection and query just fine, just the pandas dataframe to sql seems to be a problem.

Comment: @joris Hey, I tried your previous suggestion of swapping connection with just the engine piece and that worked on 15.2! I am now just getting an error where it is attempting to add an "index" to the header row. Trying by adding Index=False to see if that fixes it.

Comment: @joris so that worked! Upgrading to 15.2 and replacing the connection var with the engine var fixed it. Thanks for the help. If you submit that for an answer, I'll make sure to accept it.

Comment: Put it in an answer. I suppose a better error message would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide the sqlalchemy `engine` to `to_sql` and not the raw `connection`. Supplying the DBAPI connection is only supported for sqlite3 databases (see [docstring](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)).

Further, a pandas version of 0.14 or larger is needed for this functionality (before, only sqlite and mysql were supported)