# Error when using Pandas to write SQL to Oracle: TypeError: expecting string, unicode or buffer object

Tags: python, oracle, pandas

Error when using Pandas to write SQL to Oracle: TypeError: expecting string, unicode or buffer object while trying to use:

Pandas v 0.15.2

SqlAlchemy v 0.9.8

```
merged.to_sql('name_of_table', ora, schema='schema', if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Here is my engine creation string:

```
ora = create_engine('oracle://name:pass@site.domain.com:1521/instance')
```

I had, had an issue before [here on the site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28698931/loading-dataframe-from-pandas-to-sql-for-oracle-yields-and-error-ora-00911-in), but that was fixed with the help of Joris. After that was corrected it worked once and then started to prompt the error above.

I have tried [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032487/error-while-trying-to-write-pandas-dataframe-to-oracle-using-to-sql), [and this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238423/python-cx-oracle-expecting-string-unicode-or-buffer-object), but to no avail.

Here is the full error:

```
merged.to_sql('name_of_table', ora, schema='schema', if_exists='append', index=False)Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 966, in to_sql
dtype=dtype)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 538, in to_sql
chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1172, in to_sql
table.insert(chunksize)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 717, in insert
self._execute_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 692, in _execute_insert
conn.execute(self.insert_statement(), data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 729, in execute
return meth(self, multiparams, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 322, in _execute_on_connection
return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 826, in _execute_clauseelement
compiled_sql, distilled_params
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 958, in _execute_context
context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1162, in _handle_dbapi_exception
util.reraise(*exc_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 928, in _execute_context
context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/oracle/cx_oracle.py", line 941, in do_executemany
cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
TypeError: expecting string, unicode or buffer object
```

Funny enough, if I write it to a csv, then read the csv back into a new dataframe, it will begin write that to Oracle.

Example:

```
merged.to_csv('name.csv', sep=',', index=False, dtype=object)
merged1 = pd.read_csv('name.csv', dtype=object)
```

Then it will get further,but a new error pops up:
    sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (DatabaseError) ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CLOB

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the output of `merged.info()` and `merged1.info()`. Further, do you have NaN values? Do you have the same problem if you only try to append the first rows of the dataframe (`merged.head().to_sql(...)`)? You can also try to pass `echo=True` to `create_engine` to get a more verbose output of what is going on.

Comment: @Joris, sorry for the long term delay on this, but I figured it out. I will post an answer to my own question here in a second.

Comment: Certainly post your own answer, I am interested in the solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question, even though it is a little late. This revolved around being a dtype issue between the database and the data frame. Resolving the data frame to similar dtypes as the table allowed it to write successfully.

Thanks again @Joris